# How can i send email making a confimation link to click it?

Tags: python, django, registration, confirm, email-confirmation

models.py:

```
class Users(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='0')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    passwordrepeat = models.CharField('Repeat Password', max_length=300)
    password_token = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='0')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    email_token = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email_token_expiry = models.DateTimeField()
    tos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_action = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='0')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

class UsersModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'passwordrepeat', 'email')
        widgets = {
            'password' : PasswordInput(),
            'passwordrepeat' : PasswordInput(),
        }
```

views.py:

```
def register(request):
    flag = True
    possible = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    token = ''

    current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()

    user = UsersModelForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userf = UsersModelForm(request.POST)
        username = userf.data['username']
        password = userf.data['password']
        passwordrepeat = userf.data['passwordrepeat']
        email = userf.data['email']

        password = bcrypt.hashpw(password,bcrypt.gensalt())
        passwordrepeat = bcrypt.hashpw(passwordrepeat,bcrypt.gensalt())

        userf.data['password'] = password
        userf.data['passwordrepeat'] = passwordrepeat

        if password != passwordrepeat:
            flag = False
            passVariable = {'user':user, 'flag': False}
            return render_to_response('register.html', passVariable, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

        elif password == passwordrepeat:
            for i in range(1,10):
                temp = random.choice(possible)
                token = token + temp

            print token
            if userf.is_valid():
                check = userf.save(commit=False)
                check.email_token = token
                check.email_token_expiry = current_datetime + timedelta(1)
                check.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        return render_to_response('register.html', {"user": user, 'flag': True}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

After saving the data into table, i need to send the user with that token to confirm the email address for registration. How can i do this?

It will be very much appreciated if someone help me to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

:-)

Comment: I need to send message creating a link with token. How can i send the email with that link?

Comment: I think you need to read a bit the above link carefully... the example above gives you everything you need. You would need to extract the token from the object you made (or keep a reference to it) and then insert it into the body. I suspect that what you really want *is* django-registration as it is very adaptable, as the answer below says.

Answer (score 3):

Use [django registration](https://github.com/nathanborror/django-registration), it comes with all this logic and more, for free. Note that it's easier to start with some [template examples](https://github.com/banterability/django-registration-templates).

Comment: I won't use django registration. I want to make a custom one.

Comment: Ok. If you like to reinvent the wheel, you can recode the ORM as well. Django is so boring with all the stuff that already work.

Comment: What do you mean by ORM? Can you post the link of the code of that ORM? Are you talking about this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/ , I don't want to recode ORM, i want to write my own registration/auth.

Comment: That was a sarcastic comment.